# How to remove redundant (active and disconnected) audio devices from Windows 10 audio menu?

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi

I recently had my PC connected to my LG TV through the only HDMI output on my PC.
For some reason, Windows created three copies of the TV in the sound widget.
Only one of these actually worked at any one time (although annoyingly, which one worked would change after e.g. using a headset or putting the PC to sleep).  As of now, only one of these appears as disconnected.

[image: Windows 10 Sound widget]

Being as I now have a different, sound capable monitor attached to this HDMI port, there is no reason for the other devices to be present.
I would have thought that there should only ever be one output listed (the HDMI port) with the name changing to reflect the currently connected device.

I know that I can disable these devices manually, but as Windows seems to like adding extra redundant devices, and I have no plans to reconnect to the TV any time soon, is there a way to remove these device listings pernamently?

They do not appear in device manager (even when un-hiding hidden devices) so cannot be removed in this way, and the "uninstall driver" button (and all related buttons) are greyed out in the Properties window.

Comment: We can disable the lists that are not needed.
Right click on the blank space, uncheck "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices".

Comment: @DaisyZhou I know this.  I'm aiming to remove them entirely - especially as at least two of them are "clones" that shouldn't be there in the first place

Answer (score 0):

The device disappear from the "settings">"manage sound and device" when I disabled it **in the `device manager`** (under "audio").

I suppose we can delete it by simply uninstalling its driver there.

[Someone](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/trouble-removing-an-audio-device-from-settings/4ea62cd5-4798-48b7-97a7-76f15743c203?auth=1) confirms it works:

> Try checking if that audio device has an audio controller in Device
> Manager > Sound, video and game controllers. If so, right-click on it
>
> > select Uninstall device > check the option "Delete the driver software for this device" > click Uninstall. Restart your computer and
> > see if it will still appear.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is super old but.. 
If you show disabled devices and go to the properties of the device and there go to the properties of the controller information and at the bottom you should see an option to uninstall device. Although I wouldn't recommend uninstalling the software/driver for it, which it should ask you if you would like to as you uninstall the device.